# Hide the "Buy now " Button for configurable products

Tags: configurable-product, addtocart

plese visit configurable product: [here](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/ship.html) i am using following code to display "BUY NOW" button.

template path hint : [here](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/ship.html?tp=1&code=toy)

is there any way to hide the "BUY NOW" button for configurable products

```
app/design/frontend/default/default/template/mpassignproduct/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml

<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $buttonTitle = $this->__('Add to Cart'); ?>
<?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
    <div class="add-to-cart">
        <?php if(!$_product->isGrouped()): ?>
        <label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Qty:') ?></label>
        <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $this->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" />
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php
            $assignPro=Mage::getModel('mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct')->getAssignProDetails($_product->getId());
        ?>
        <?php if($assignPro['assignCount']): ?>
            <?php if($assignPro['sellerqty'] > 0): ?>

                <button type="button" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" id="product-addtocart-button" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></span></span></button>

                <div style="clear: both; padding-top: 10px;">
               <button type="button" onclick="jQuery('#buy_now').val('buy_now');productAddToCartForm.submit(this)" class="button buy-now btn btn-block btn-express-buynow"><span><span>Buy Now</span></span></button>
            </div>

            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php else: ?>
            <button type="button" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" id="product-addtocart-button" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></span></span></button>

            <div style="clear: both; padding-top: 10px;">
                <button type="button" onclick="jQuery('#buy_now').val('buy_now');productAddToCartForm.submit(this)" class="button buy-now btn btn-block btn-express-buynow"><span><span>Buy Now</span></span></button>
            </div>

        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('', true, true) ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Hi, can you share how did you manage to create this buy now button? Any other codes and files to add? Thanks!

Comment: @KiDCajes check this [link](http://blog.fusedwebspace.co.uk/adding-buy-now-button-to-magento-1-9-that-skips-the-shopping-cart/)

Comment: @nsdlfefinedieicbe thanks for the link but this one doesn't have validation for items with custom option or configurable.

Comment: @KiDCajes than its better if you create new question with that you followed this link and  you wanted custom option or configurable.

Comment: I already did but no one seems replying sad http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/116365/magento-1-7-buy-now-button-with-custom-options-and-configurable-item-checker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $buttonTitle = $this->__('Add to Cart'); ?>
<?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
    <div class="add-to-cart">
        <?php if(!$_product->isGrouped()): ?>
        <label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Qty:') ?></label>
        <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $this->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" />
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php
            $assignPro=Mage::getModel('mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct')->getAssignProDetails($_product->getId());
        ?>
        <?php if($assignPro['assignCount']): ?>
            <?php if($assignPro['sellerqty'] > 0): ?>

                <button type="button" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" id="product-addtocart-button" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></span></span></button>
            <?php if($_product->getTypeId() != 'configurable'):?>
                <div style="clear: both; padding-top: 10px;">
               <button type="button" onclick="jQuery('#buy_now').val('buy_now');productAddToCartForm.submit(this)" class="button buy-now btn btn-block btn-express-buynow"><span><span>Buy Now</span></span></button>
            </div>
           <?php endif;?>

            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php else: ?>
            <button type="button" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" id="product-addtocart-button" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></span></span></button>

          <?php if($_product->getTypeId() != 'configurable'):?>
            <div style="clear: both; padding-top: 10px;">
                <button type="button" onclick="jQuery('#buy_now').val('buy_now');productAddToCartForm.submit(this)" class="button buy-now btn btn-block btn-express-buynow"><span><span>Buy Now</span></span></button>
            </div>
         <?php endif;?>

        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('', true, true) ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

We are checking product's type and act accordingly.

`<?php if($_product->getTypeId() != 'configurable'):?>`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getAssignProDetails() on boolean

Comment: `getAssignProDetails` is a function only exist in OP's module. You will need to remove all of those related dependencies.

Comment: thank you Adarsh.I have followed your advice and have succeeded.is there a way for the Buy Now button after clicking it will be directed to the Shopping Cart page?

Comment: Check this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/137324/add-to-cart-not-redirecting-to-cart-page

Comment: but I have turned off the `"after adding a product redirect to shopping cart"` feature so that `Add To Cart` is not directed to the `Shoppping Cart` page. So there are 2 buttons : `Buy Now` button and the `Add To Cart` button. The `Buy Now` button will be directed to the `Shopping Cart` page, and the `Add To Cart` button remains on the page.