# Magento 1.7 Buy Now Button with Custom options and Configurable item checker

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, onepage-checkout, custom-options, addtocart

I used this approach for the buy now button on product page

app/design/frontend/your_template/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml

```
<script>
function setcheckoutLocation(location)
{
jQuery.ajax({
type:”GET”,
url:location,
success:function(data){
window.location.href = “http://www.your-site.com/checkout/onepage/”;
}
});

}
</script>
```

app/design/frontend/your_template/default/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml

```
    <button type=”button” title=”Buy Now” class=”button btn-cart” 
onclick=”setcheckoutLocation(‘<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>’)”><span><span>Buy Now</span></span></button>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml(”, true, true) ?>
```

Refrence : [link](http://blog.fusedwebspace.co.uk/adding-buy-now-button-to-magento-1-9-that-skips-the-shopping-cart/)

But when an item has custom option or a configurable product, it doesn't prompt "required" entry like what the ADD TO CART does. Instead it will say "Shopping cart is Empty". Any solution for this? Thanks!

Comment: Check There Your Question's Answer [Go with this link](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/128673/magento-buy-now-button-for-configurable-products)