# Add to cart not redirecting to cart page

Tags: magento-1.9

I Am using my custom design , it is not been redirecting the add to cart button to Cart page. is there any function or url i need to set in admin panel ?

Comment: please enable the .xml details and check in app/design/frontend/base/default/layout.checkout

Answer (score 1):

system > configuration > sales > checkout > shopping cart > after adding a product redirect to shopping cart

[image]

Comment: it is already set to yes

Comment: why it is magento2 screenshot if the question is tagged magento1.9?

Comment: for magento1 the feature is in the same path, starting from system menu